# Modify git repo to allow forks to update without overwriting particular files

Tags: git, github

## Background

I have an unusual scenario, in that I have a master repo that my students have pulled. This means that the topology is 1 master and 70 children.

The repo contains some files that are exercises, e.g.:

```
def write_this_code_good():
    """Explanation of what to do."""
    pass
```

and other files that test those files. Being inflicted with intermittent idiocy, I made some mistakes in the tests, which I've now fixed.

I have also been using this repo to show how to complete the exercises (I told you I was inflicted with intermittent idiocy). This means that my changes are dated *after* their changes.

All the commits we are dealing with here have been committed and pushed.

## The problem

I'd like the students to be able to be able to add the parent repo as an upstream and pull from it. However, in my tests, the commits I've been making in demos are overwriting their work.

## What I've tried already

I've tried reverting. That works to set the state of the repo back to its state when they got it but, because it adds another commit to do so, if they pulled that it would reset their repo too. (Rather than leave it untouched.)

## what I *think* I need

I think I need to actually remove the commits from certain files so that there is no diff to apply.

## The question[s]

1. is my intuition correct? Is that the right way to fix it?
2. How do I actually achieve that?
3. do any of the GUI tools support that? (It would be nice to actually see what I'm doing in a complicated scenario like this)

Answer (score 1):

No need to revert.

All they need is to add your updated repo as upstream, fetch from it, and rebase on top of your updated upstream/master

```
cd /path/to/a/student/repo
git checkout a_student_branch
git remote add upstream /url/of/your/updated/repo
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

If the student directly cloned from your repo, then there is no need for a new "upstream" remote: they can directly fetch and rebase from origin.

Comment: Oddly, this worked when i tested it locally, but overwrote the test-student's work. My guess is that my test environment has more recent commits than the updates to the tests. My understanding is that the rebase is supposed to play the commits from my version, then theirs, regardless of the timestamp.

Comment: @Ben: yes, dates are irrelevant. It's not exactly "play" commits though. Rebase *copies* commits, using `git cherry-pick` (or its moral equivalent). The key questions to address are: *what gets copied*, *to where*, and *what happens to the originals*.

Comment: @Ben yes, timestamps are not important here. Make sure your students have committed the work in progress before rebasing their branch: each of their commit will be cherry-picked on top of yours.